# Using Joomla 2.5 user_profile fields in PHP

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using the following  to get the data for a user to be printed on a label.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$uid = $user->id;

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering'))
    ->from('#__user_profiles')
    ->where('user_id LIKE $uid')
    ->order('ordering ASC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $result as $row ) {
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.firstname') $fname = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.middlename') $mname = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.lastname') $lname = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.address1') $aline1 = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.address2') $aline2 = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.city') $city = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.state') $state = $row->profile_value;
   if ($row->profile_key == 'profile.postalcode') $zipcode = $row->profile_value;
}
```

Is there a simpler way of writing this code?

I'm using Joomla 2.5.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile( $user->id );`

to get all the  fields of a user profile for a particular user. Then use as

`$address1 = $profile->profile['address1'];`

to access the required fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `loadObjectList` the value 'profile_key' which would key your array to the profile key so you could skip parsing it yourself:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$uid = $user->id;

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering'))
    ->from('#__user_profiles')
    ->where('user_id LIKE $uid')
    ->order('ordering ASC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->loadObjectList('profile_key');

$fname = $result['profile.firstname']->profile_value;
// no need to loop on this
// can just grab values from the array as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/user/helper.php#L198

JUserHelper::getProfile() will help you out.